# How to open an MSG E-Mail via JAVA using Outlook OLE

Tags: java, outlook, ole

I would like to embedd Outlook(2010) via OLE into my Java application to just open an msgfile

```
OleFrame oleframe = new OleFrame(myComposite, SWT.NONE);
olesite = new OleClientSite(oleframe, SWT.NONE, "Outlook.Application", new File("myTestMail.msg"));
olesite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);
```

The result ist just empty Composite and nothing happens.

With other Microsoft Office Applications (e.g. MS Word, the code above works perfectly)

```
olesite = new OleClientSite(oleframe, SWT.NONE, "Word.Document", new File("myTest_Document.docx"));
```

**Alternative  approach**

when using this code

```
olesite = new OleClientSite(oleframe, SWT.NONE, "OVCtl.OVCtl");
```

i get an embedded outlook showing my inbox mail-list, but i do not know how to tell this ole object to open the msgfile (appending the "File" parameter does not work)

Does any of you has an idea  - maybe a workaround - how i could solve this tricky problem?

Thanking you in advance for helping me

Shane

Answer (score 0):

Outlook.Application cannot be embedded as a control. If you want to show the contents of an MSG file, you might have a better luck with a preview handler. Don't know if Javas can handle it though as it is not IDispatch based.